# Selecting Seats after booking from BudgetAir

Tags: air-travel, bookings, seating

I have found some affordable tickets on BudgetAir (could be any other service - specifying it just for the reference in case someone needs it) and I wonder if I can choose the seats from the carrier (Kuwait Airways)'s own page later on? I know they allow it for the normal tickets purchased from their website, but do they facilitate it even for the 3rd party ticket purchases too? Issue with BudgetAir is that its not showing some of the seats in seat selection which are available on main KWI Airways page.

Comment: never use 3rd party websites, this just being a small reason for it

Comment: @chx I have concerns about 3rd party websites too. But its giving some discount.

Comment: Aye but then irrops happen and you will rue the saved little money. A tale as old as time. This site is full of such stories. https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168635/4188 https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171242/4188 comes to mind and that's just within the last year...

Comment: @chx Had some concerns. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: It is difficult to predict what you will have access to. In some cases with the PNR you’ll have access to seat selection exactly as if you had bought directly from the airline. Some other times you won’t have access at all. Also, it’s possible you have a restricted fare which does not give access to all seats (especially any you have to pay extra for, but there may be more restrictions). There’s usually a reason for the discount…

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer for all airlines and all booking sites.
Some airlines will allow people who bought from an other seller all the same perks as people who bought from the airline itself.
Other airlines restrict people who bought from other sellers in some or many ways.

Airlines do not have to publish what rules they follow, when they change them nor whether they keep the same rules for all resellers.

So even when you know about the rules for the combination of airline and reseller you can run into problems when the airline changes those rules.

A good reason to avoid resellers is that they have often proven difficult in getting your money back when the airline cancels the flight, in getting you your money if you get a delay and the airline is bound to compensate.
And often they sell you 'a ticket' for two flights which are unrelated for the airline(s) and leave you hanging when one of them is delayed or cancelled.

And one small thing I noticed myself, the airline send an e-mail to announce a change in departure time and the reseller took 24 hours to send on the mail. In my case it was a departure a bit later which did not matter anything, but it could have cost me big if I had had two different flights or  if the change had been bigger. For me the reason to avoid resellers since.

Comment: Yeah noticed Etihad airways (recently booked directly from their website) sending a barrage of email/sms to notify the change in departure time. Indeed can be costy in the case of reseller.